# how to save xml file with ajax and javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I am trying to add an element to an xml file. I have checked the program with debugger and I saw it really adds the element to the xml file but when I stop the running the file didn't saved any changes.
here is the javascript file:

```
var xmlhttp = LoadXMLHttp();
var xmlDoc=LoadXMLDoc("XMLFile.xml");;
function LoadXMLHttp() {
    var xmlHttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    return xmlHttp;
}
function LoadXMLDoc(FileName) {
    xmlhttp.open("GET", FileName, false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    return xmlhttp.responseXML;
}
function CreateXmlElement() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        newMessageElement = xmlDoc.createElement("message");
        newTextElement = xmlDoc.createElement("text");
        newText = xmlDoc.createTextNode("I am fine");
        newTextElement.appendChild(newText);
        newMessageElement.appendChild(newTextElement);
        x = xmlDoc.documentElement;
        x.appendChild(newMessageElement);
    }
}
function AddXMLElement() {
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "Default.aspx", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = CreateXmlElement;
    xmlhttp.send(xmlDoc);
}
```

And here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<conversation>
  <message>
    <text>Hi</text>
  </message>
  <message>
    <text>How are you?</text>
  </message>
</conversation>
```

By the way:

1. I don't know jquery or `php` but I do know `asp.net`
2. If I change the open url to "XMLFile.xml", I get an error message that says "method not allowed".
3. I have a button that activates the `AddXMLElement()` function.

Comment: What browsers do you have to support? That whole thing on top is really crufty and is useful to support browsers like IE6 and IE5.5 which I doubt you actually have to support. Please clarify on that.

Answer (score 1):

You're executing the `CreateXmlElement` method as a callback to your AJAX post. So you modify your document **after** sending it to the server instead of before. That's why the modified document is not saved.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
function CreateXmlElement() {
    newMassageElement = xmlDoc.createElement("massage");
    newTextElement = xmlDoc.createElement("text");
    newText = xmlDoc.createTextNode("I am fine");
    newTextElement.appendChild(newText);
    newMassageElement.appendChild(newTextElement);
    x = xmlDoc.documentElement;
    x.appendChild(newMassageElement);
}
function AddXMLElement() {
    CreateXmlElement();

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "Default.aspx", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
    xmlhttp.send(xmlDoc);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I undstand you correctly. Do you mean the xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = CreateXmlElement; should be written before the "open"?

Comment: @Xshibi I've updated my answer, but I have to admit that it's a little unclear what you're trying to do. As far as I can tell: 1) get file from server, 2) modify XML, 3) post modified XML back to server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is still not working. I am basically trying to create a chat system for my school project. The problem is that when the user(me) trying to send a message to another user, the message does not add to the xml file that contains the conversation. So  I created a mini project just to solve this problem.

Comment: @Xshibi Are you saving the posted XML file again on the server side at all?

Comment: That save function does not work in javascript, and i thought the post saves the file. Do you have any idea how should i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This construct works for me. It opens a xml file, changes one Tag and saves it back to the server.. 
HTML part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>xml </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="xml_tag0" >
      zero  
    </div>  
    <div id="xml_tag" >
      Start!!  
    </div>
    <div id="xml_tag2" >
      Start!!  
    </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/test_xml_load_and_save.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </html>
```

The JavaScript Part(test_xml_load_and_save.js):

```
      $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '../php/B.xml',
      dataType: 'text',
      success: function(xml){

            doc = $.parseXML(xml)
            $('#xml_tag').text($(doc).find('row FIELD2').eq(2).text());  
            console.log($(doc).find('row FIELD2').eq(2).text());    
            $(doc).find('row FIELD2').eq(2).text('50%');

            xml = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(doc);

            //var dataString = '<test></test>';
            var dataString = xml; 
            $('#xml_tag0').text(xml);

            $.ajax({  
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../php/ToXML.php',          
            contentType: "text/xml",
            dataType:'text',
            data: {xml : dataString},
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                $('#xml_tag2').text(response);
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log('LOG success: '+data); 
                $('#xml_tag2').text('LOG success: '+data);
            } 
            });



      }});
```

and the PHP part (php/ToXML.php):

```
      <?php
      header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');


      $data = $_POST['xml'];
      $xml = file_get_contents('php://input');
      $xml = rawurldecode($xml);
      $xml = str_replace('+', '', $xml);
      $xml = str_replace('xml=', '', $xml);
      //echo ":".$xml;
      $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . $xml;

      $filename = "B.xml";
      $f = fopen($filename, 'w+');
      fwrite($f, $xml);
      fclose($f);
      echo "Ok";
      ?>
```

the XML file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>

  <root>
  <row>
  <FIELD1>Cat1</FIELD1>
  <FIELD2>Min</FIELD2>
  <FIELD3>Neutral</FIELD3>
  <FIELD4>Max</FIELD4>
  </row>


  <row>
  <FIELD1>Liquid</FIELD1>
  <FIELD2>0%</FIELD2>
  <FIELD3>7%</FIELD3>
  <FIELD4>65%</FIELD4>
  </row>


  <row>
  <FIELD1>Bonds</FIELD1>
  <FIELD2>25%</FIELD2>
  <FIELD3>50%</FIELD3>
  <FIELD4>70%</FIELD4>
  </row>


  <row>
  <FIELD1>Equities</FIELD1>
  <FIELD2>10%</FIELD2>
  <FIELD3>25%</FIELD3>
  <FIELD4>35%</FIELD4>
  </row>


  <row>
  <FIELD1>AltInv</FIELD1>
  <FIELD2>0%</FIELD2>
  <FIELD3>18%</FIELD3>
  <FIELD4>30%</FIELD4>
  </row>

  </root>
```